# Angular JS table with ng-repeat and radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, html-table, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make a table using ng-repeat that has a radio button selector at the start of each row. The table looks like this:

```
<table>
     <tbody>  
         <tr ng-repeat="model in modelList">
              <td>
                 <input type="radio" ng-model="model.select"></input>
              </td>
             <td>{{ model.NDPName }}</td>
             <td>{{ model.OEM }}</td>
             <td>{{ model.version }}</td>
             <td>{{ model.dateAdded }}</td>
             <td>{{ model.validUntil }}</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

The ng-repeat is taking from a modelList that looks like:

```
    $scope.modelList =
    [
        {
            select: false,
            NDPName: "NDP1",
            OEM: "CHOAM Inc.",
            version: "01",
            dateAdded: "Jan 1, 2013",
            validUntil: "Jan 1, 2014",
        },
        {
            select: false,
            NDPName: "NDP2",
            OEM: "Tyrell Corp.",
            version: "01",
            dateAdded: "Jan 1, 2014",
            validUntil: "Jan 1, 2015",
        },
        {
            select: false,
            NDPName: "NDP3",
            OEM: "Stark Industries",
            version: "01",
            dateAdded: "Jan 1, 2015",
            validUntil: "Jan 1, 2016",
        },
        {
            select: false,
            NDPName: "NDP4",
            OEM: "Monsters Inc.",
            version: "01",
            dateAdded: "Jan 1, 2016",
            validUntil: "Jan 1, 2017",
        },
        {
            select: false,
            NDPName: "NDP5",
            OEM: "ACME Corp",
            version: "01",
            dateAdded: "Jan 1, 2017",
            validUntil: "Jan 1, 2018",
        }
    ];
```

The problem I am running into is that the radio buttons are not behaving like radio buttons. They are each in a separate scope and will therefore allow multiple rows in the table to be selected. How can I fix this?

Comment: FYI, your `<input></input>` syntax is invalid. If you're using an XHTML doctype, it's `<input />` otherwise just `<input>`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set a `name` propertyfor the radio buttons so they will be grouped together.

```
<input type="radio" name="groupName" ng-model="model.select" />
```

[read about the name property here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_name.asp)

Comment: The simplest fixes are the easiest ones to overlook. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the name tag in the input. Then all the inputs will belong to the same group and will behave as expected:

```
<input type="radio" name="myGroup" ng-model="model" />
```

Comment: The `ng-model` should include a dot. See https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot