# dropdown selected value use only once on add button in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, selectedindex

Selected value from the drop down should be added when I click on add button, only once the value should be added to the result field. Some once can help me on this. below is code which i tried.

```
function ContactController($scope) {
 $scope.contacts = ["Apple"];
 $scope.curItem = [{
     id: "1",
     items: "Apple"
 }, {
     id: "2",
     items: "Orange"
 }, {
     id: "3",
     items: "Banana"
 }, {
     id: "4",
     items: "Apricot"
 }, {
     id: "5",
     items: "Asparagus"
 }, ];
 $scope.selectedItem = $scope.curItem[0];
```

}

View :

```
<table class="range-table" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden">
            <button class="btn btn-link" value= "Save">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select required="" style="min-width:180px;"> </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="range-table" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="contact in contacts"> <td>{{ contact }}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You didn't provide any code "below" ...

Comment: how to embed the code in satck overflow??

Comment: <table class="range-table" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="hidden"> <button class="btn btn-link" value=
            "Save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </td>

            <td><select required="" style="min-width:180px;">
                </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="range-table" width="100%">
        <tr>       
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
            <td>{{ contact }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Comment: I've made this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uPFwoHzWuiIgHGEhWgF6?p=preview   Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you so much .. Tomislav .. :) :) :)

Comment: I edited your post, adding the html you provided in comments, and fixing 2 typos (closing button tag and one <td> was <tr>.

Comment: I need a alert box.If item is already added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


        <table class="range-table" width="100%"> 
         <tr> 
            <td><input type="hidden"> <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="save(selectedItem)">Save</button> </td> 
            <td><select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.items as i.items for i in curItem" ng-init="selectedItem=curItem[0].id"></select></td> </tr> 
</table> 
<table class="range-table" width="100%"> 
          <tr> 
          <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts track by $index">
             <td>{{ contact }}</td> 
          </tr>
 </table>

</body>
```

Javascript (your controller code):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = ["Apple"]; 

  $scope.curItem=[{id:"1",items:"Apple"}, {id:"2",items:"Orange"}, {id:"3",items:"Banana"}, {id:"4",items:"Apricot"}, {id:"5",items:"Asparagus"}]; 
  $scope.save=function(i){
    if ($scope.contacts.indexOf(i) <= -1){
     $scope.contacts.push(i);
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPFwoHzWuiIgHGEhWgF6?p=preview)

Edit: It seems that you want to add value only once. I've edited my answer and plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pbNe4YVN2UZowl7fYJRc?p=preview)

Textbox should be enabled on click of other option radio button is checked

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('form.Program', function(mVal){
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.form)) return; 

    if(mVal === 'other'){
       $scope.form.OtherProgram = $scope.tmVar;
    } else {
      if($scope.form.OtherProgram !== null){
        $scope.tmVar = $scope.form.OtherProgram;
         $scope.form.OtherProgram = null;
      }
     }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>
        Program:
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="option 1" required /> option 1</label>
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="option 2" required /> option 2</label>
        <label><input type="radio" ng-model="form.Program" name="Program" value="other" required /> other</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.OtherProgram" ng-disabled="form.Program != 'other'" name="Program_Other"  ng-required ="form.Program != 'other'"/>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405953/angular-js-table-with-ng-repeat-and-radio-buttons